# C++'s std::vector and thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

Is the following code thread safe:

THREAD A

```
  std::vector<std::string> myCopy;
  with_locked_mutex(m) {
    myCopy = sharedCopy;
  }
  myCopy.clear() etc.  // -- a
```

THREAD B

```
  while(1) {
    // do things ...
    with_locked_mutex(m) {
      sharedCopy.push_back(a); // -- b
    }
  }
```

In other words, will the COW semantics of std::vector (and that of std::string also, I think) create a race condition between a and b?  If so, is there something I can do to prevent it?

Comment: Who told you that `vector` has COW semantics? (Also, it'd be more like "implemented as COW", since that's not part of the semantics.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `with_locked_mutex(m) { something }` somehow ensures that the mutex is acquired before the code block and released after, the two operations will run in mutual exclusion, so no, there won't be an issue.

And a `std::vector` cannot use copy-on-write anyway.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, `std::vector` doesn't have COW semantics. The assignment operator and copy constructor always copy every element.